# How can I obtain Function objects from methods in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, pointers

Suppose I have a simple class in Scala:

```
class Simple {
  def doit(a: String): Int = 42
}
```

How can I store in a val the Function2[Simple, String, Int] that takes two arguments (the target Simple object, the String argument), and can call doit() get me the result back?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
val f: Function2[Simple, String, Int] = _.doit(_)
```

Comment: Called "partial application." As show here it's a special case. As the name suggests, some arguments may be supplied in the partial application and the resulting function has arity N-M where N was the original method's (or function's) arity and M is the number of arguments fixed in the partial application.

Comment: Perfect. I was wondering how the compiler would figure out whether the doit method really exists; I see that explicit typing does the trick here. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

same as sepp2k, just using another syntax

```
val f = (s:Simple, str:String) => s.doit(str)
```

Answer (score 9):

For those among you that don't enjoy typing types:

```
scala> val f = (_: Simple).doit _
f: (Simple) => (String) => Int = <function1>
```

Following a method by `_` works for for any arity:

```
scala> trait Complex {                        
     |    def doit(a: String, b: Int): Boolean
     | }                                      
defined trait Complex

scala> val f = (_: Complex).doit _            
f: (Complex) => (String, Int) => Boolean = <function1>
```

This is covered by a combination of §6.23 "Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions" and §7.1 "Method Values" of the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf)

Comment: What are the practical implications of having a function of type (Simple) => (String) => Int vs. of type (Simple, String) => Int? I know the former is called with f(obj)("str") and the latter with f(obj, "str"), and the former returns another function object if just call it with one parameter list: f(obj).

But what happens behind the scenes in terms of number of objects created and number of method invocations?

Comment: Two Function1 objects rather than one Function2 object is created, with an extra level of indirection.