# Scala: How to access a shadowed function variable from an object

Tags: function, scala, object, shadowing

I would like to make the following work:

```
def foo(x:Int = 1) = {
  object obj {
    val x = foo.this.x
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to reference x from within the object. Can this be done without renaming x in one of the two spots?

Renaming the variables may not be easy when, for example, `foo` is a widely used API function with x as a named variable, while `obj` extends a 3rd party trait that has `x` as an abstract member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just introduce a new variable that has the same value as `foo`'s argument `x`, but is not shadowed?

```
def foo(x: Int): Unit = {
  val foo_x = x
  object obj {
    val x = 13
    def doStuff: Unit = printf("%d %d\n", x, foo_x);
  }
  obj.doStuff
}

foo(42)
```

Comment: Yes, this works and is what I do currently. It is acceptable, but slightly hacky (I felt like it needs a comment to explain what foo_x is for). My hope with this question was to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. There is no way to identify the outer block of the function definition.

For your syntax to work foo would have to be an object with a member x. i.e. this works:

```
class foo{
  val x = 1
  object obj {
    val x = foo.this.x
  }
}
```

`foo` also could be a singleton object extending FunctionX, which gives you something very similar to a method. But it is probably easier to just rename one of the values.

Comment: bringing up FunctionX is interesting. Perhaps I can access `foo` as an object using the method from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3238506/1705163)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Scala.

You write the code, so the easiest option will be to rename one of the `x`s and problem solved.

However, if from some reason you really need it - you can do a trick and create an `object` that will behave like your method

```
object Foo {
  self =>

  val x = 1

  def apply() = {
    object obj {
      val x1 = self.x
      val x2 = Foo.x
      // x1 == x2, just 2 different ways of doing this
    }
  }
}
```

Because the `apply` method is implemented you can use it as you would use a function `Foo()`