# Access parent scope variable in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a simple unit test, like

```
"foo" in {

  val probe = TestProbe()  

  val actor = TestActorRef(Props(new MyActor("blabla")) {
    override def createActor: ActorRef = probe.ref
  }))

}
```

However, class `MyActor` contains a field named `probe` hence my override reference this fields instead of my local test variable. The code does not compile (as `probe` field does not have a `ref` member).
I can of course simply rename the variable, however I would like how to do it properly - I mean how to reference the variable from my local context, how to solve this 'name clash'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question asked here: [Scala: How to access a shadowed function variable from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712688/scala-how-to-access-a-shadowed-function-variable-from-an-object) although I wouldn't consider it a duplicate.

But the same answer applies:

No, this is not possible. There is no way to reference the outer variable without renaming it, because there is no identify for the outer block.